# What does the phrase 'nets out' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Wally: I worked every night for a month to come up with a detailed quote for one of our potential customers.

Dilbert: Then those weasels used our quote to get a better price from their regular vendor!

Dilbert: Did you really do all of that work?

Wally: No, but it **nets out** the same.

What does the phrase **nets out** mean in this context?

Comment: Why don't you look up a dictionary? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/net-out It means almost same amount.

Comment: @MaulikV, I landed on the same link that's mentioned in the comment. But it seems the meaning was given in a monetary context.

Comment: It has the other meaning as well. To meet the required amount is what it says irrespective of monetary matter.

Comment: @MaulikV, that is very correct. But I was not able to digest the explanation to use the phrase in its general sense. Some more usages of the phrase would be very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something *nets out* - meaning has/results in a summary value, including various side-effects - for whatever form of value you're assigning.

Something *nets out the same* if the outcome is of the same value. It can also *net out better* or *worse*.

Your example is from a humorous source, so it's used tongue-in-cheek: "I worked every night for a month" yielding the same result as just coming up with the figure with minimum effort.

Let's take some more standard examples:

> "Why are you shopping at the corner store instead of going to Wal-Mart? The prices are much lower!"
>
> "If you count the cost of fuel and the time wasted getting there, the corner store nets out better."

or

> If we wait for the bus now, we'll net out about the same time-wise as just walking there on foot, and that's assuming the bus won't be delayed.

---

And something counter-intuitive:

> The device, the user manuals, cables, inner packaging, outer packaging, pallet and securing straps will net out over thirty kilograms, and that pushes us into 'cargo package' territory.

The expression *to net out* comes directly from *net weight*:

> *Actual, computed, or estimated weight of a good without its container and/or packaging. Gross weight less tare weight equals net weight.*

...which in this case means something exactly opposite!

Answer (score 0):

We have a number of verbs that partner with **out**:

turns out

comes out

nets out

and **out** refers to the abstract idea of *become manifest*.

That is how events will unfold.

**nets** contributes the sense the outcome involves numbers or a combination of factors some of which are "positive" and others "negative".   The outcome is the result when the positives are reduced by the negatives.

> I charged you a late fee but didn't charge you for bringing the car back with the gas tank nearly empty.  I could charge you for the gas and waive the late fee, but it would net out the same.